# Повторная смена цвета поля по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при повторном нажатии на поле становилось обратно черного цвета?

То есть один клик - поле красное, ещё один - поле черное.

```js
$('#submit').click(function() {
    $('#txt').css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

```css
input {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: я бы предложил не менять css свойство, а делать toggleClass()

Comment: @Sergey Alekseev Я не знаю эту китайскую грамоту, но наверное что-то должно выглядеть вроде следующего $('#txt').css('background-color') === 'red' ? $('#txt').css('background-color', '#000') :  $('#txt').css('background-color', 'red');

Comment: @Reinq спасибо, то, что надо

Answer (score 2):

1. Озвученный вариант со сменой класса:

```js
$('#submit').on("click", function() {
    $('#txt').toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

```css
input {
    background-color: #000;
}

.clicked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

При таком варианте нужно чтобы стили для класса были "важнее" "базовых" стилей. Этого можно достичь с помощью приоритетов селекторов (например, селектор класса важнее селектора тега) или с помощью использования `!important` в стилях.

2. Также можно хранить дополнительный цвет в качестве data-атрибута и менять значение с текущим местами при клике:

```js
$('#submit').on("click", function() {
    var $txt = $('#txt');
    var currentColor = $txt.css('background-color');
    $txt.css('background-color', $txt.data('color'));
    $txt.data('color', currentColor);
})
```

```css
input {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" data-color="red">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

При таком подходе не нужно думать о приоритетах стилей, равно как и код можно будет использовать для любого количества элементов.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю ни JavaScript, ни jQuery, но я отвечу!:)

Я тут смастерил пример с JavaScript, используя условный оператор.

```
<!DOCTYPE html />

<html lang = "ru">

<body>
    <div>
        <input type = "text" id = "txt" style = "background-color: #000;"/>
        <button id = "submit">Submit</button>
   </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function () {
            var txtStyle = document.getElementById("txt").style;

            txtStyle.getPropertyValue("background-color") === "red" ?
            txtStyle.setProperty("background-color", "#000") :
            txtStyle.setProperty("background-color", "red");
        };

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Он работает.

Думаю, что что- то вроде этого можно сделать и на jQuery, то есть вставить условный оператор. Что-то наподобие такого:

```
$('#txt').css('background-color') === 'red' ? 
$('#txt').css('background-color', '#000') : 
$('#txt').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Конечно, лучше было бы просто менять классы, описанные в таблице CSS, у этого элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Добавив, к примеру, флаг нажатия. Логика такова, что в начальном состоянии флаг равен `true`. А при нажатии становится `false`. И обратно. Выглядеть JS будет как-то так:

```
var flag = true;
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if (flag == true) {
        $('#txt').css('background-color', 'red'); 
        flag = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#txt').css('background-color', 'black'); 
        flag = true;
    }
})
```

Comment: Да, я опирался на то, что ТС начинающий. Хотел написать как можно очевидный код.

Comment: Вполне может быть, что начинающий. Проблема в том, что в таком случае он, скорее всего, ещё долго так писать и будет. Но право ваше, равно как и код верный. Тогда про тернарный оператор и `flag = !flag`, сводящие тело функции к двум строкам, даже заикаться не буду.